# pygame won't bring up a window

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi3

I am learning python on my raspberry pi 3, so I thought that I would try to add some graphics. I was trying to bring up a window to add my graphics on, but it brings up the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/python_programmes/pygame1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/home/pi/python programmes/pygame.py", line 6, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'
```

The code that I entered is:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
size = [700, 500]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("My game")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    clock.tick(20)
pygame.quit()
```

I deleted all files that where called pygame.py, but there is still one that is called pygame.pyc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i keep getting the error 'module' object has no attribute 'init'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231200/i-keep-getting-the-error-module-object-has-no-attribute-init)

Comment: @skrx It isn't, as I tried what it says in the question, and called it something that is no pygame.py, and it still comes up with the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a local file named `File "/home/pi/python programmes/pygame.py"` ,
so what happens is your script not importing pygame library rather it  is importing pygame.py from your local folder File `"/home/pi/python programmes/"` .  your just need to rename this file  from pygame.py to something else and your issue is fixed.

Comment: does that include pygame.pyc?

Comment: @toheedNiza It is all right, I changed the name of pygame.pyc to pygame1.pyc and it worked! Thank you so much that is really helpful. If only all computer problems were that easy!

Comment: i am not sure , but you should remove that as well if it is in your `/home/pi/python programmes/` path

Comment: OK. I deleted it and it still works. That was really helpful! Thank you so much